# How to wait for 10 seconds between execution of two scenarios in cucumber feature file

Tags: cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java

I am new to cucumber. I have two scenarios 1 and 2 in cucumber feature file.

Scenario 1 should wait for 10 seconds after its completion and then scenario 2 should start.

Request help here.

Comment: Do you have only two scenarios? Do they always run sequentially? Do they always run in the same order?

Comment: Yes only two scenarios and the run sequentially with the same order.

Answer (score 1):

You can tag your scenario that should wait and use the conditional hook that would delay your tagged test for given amount of time.

Say you have this feature file:

```
Feature: blah

  Scenario:
    Given Test1

  @wait
  Scenario:
    Given Test2
```

so you could have definitions like this:

```java
public class StepDef {

    @Given("Test1")
    public void test1(){
        System.out.println("Doing test1");
    }

    @Given("Test2")
    public void test2(){
        System.out.println("Doing test2");
    }

    @Before("@wait")
    public void doingWait(){
        try {
            System.out.println("Waiting for 10 sec..");
            Thread.sleep(10_000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

}
```

The above would run first scenario right away and the second one after 10 seconds delay.